# ‘NoneType’ object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow

updated: tried the code and still got the same error:
[image: updated: tried the code and still got the same error]

```
import tensorflow as tf
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
```

And then this error shows up.

> TypeError: ‘NoneType’ object is not callable
>
> dtype, shape, name

Comment: you should provide all code, it seems shape and name are not defined anywhere in your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure you read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

this is how you should define a placehoder

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1024, 1024))
```

and if you want to be consistent with your code , you have to initialize those variable used in your code

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> shape=(1024,1024)
>>> dtype=tf.float32
>>> name = "input"
>>> x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
```

**EDIT:** this is what i get when i run your code

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dtype' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code cannot works too. I still got the same error : (

Comment: are you sure tensorflow is installed?

Comment: if it wasn't wouldn't that be an `ImportError`?

Comment: i have a feeling that the command may be run in the shell instead of an python interpreter